# Scrape XML response from ajax request with python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get the data that get loaded into the chart of [this page](https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?groupField=none&sortField=ter&sortOrder=asc&from=search&isin=IE00B3VWN518&tab=chart) when hitting the max (time range) button. The data are loaded with an ajax request.

I inspected the request and tried to reproduce it with the requests python library but I'm only able to retrieve the 1-year data from this chart.

Here is the code I used:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?0-4.0-tabs-panel-chart-dates-ptl_max&groupField=none&sortField=ter&sortOrder=asc&from=search&isin=IE00B3VWN518&tab=chart&_=1576272593482")
r.content
```

I also tried to use Session:

```
from requests import Session
session = Session()

session.head('http://justetf.com')

response = session.get(
    url='https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?0-4.0-tabs-panel-chart-dates-ptl_max&groupField=none&sortField=ter&sortOrder=asc&from=search&isin=IE00B3VWN518&tab=chart&_=1575929227619',
    data = {"0-4.0-tabs-panel-chart-dates-ptl_max":"",
            "groupField":"none","sortField":"ter",
            "sortOrder":"asc","from":"search",
            "isin":"IE00B3VWN518",
            "tab":"chart",
            "_":"1575929227619"
           },

    headers={
        'Host': 'www.justetf.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
        'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Wicket-Ajax': 'true',
        'Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL': 'en/etf-profile.html?0&amp;groupField=none&amp;sortField=ter&amp;sortOrder=asc&amp;from=search&amp;isin=IE00B3VWN518&amp;tab=chart',
        'Wicket-FocusedElementId': 'id28',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?groupField=none&sortField=ter&sortOrder=asc&from=search&isin=IE00B3VWN518&tab=chart',
        'Cookie': 'locale_=en; _ga=GA1.2.1297456970.1574289342; cookieconsent_status=dismiss; AWSALB=QMWHJxgfcpLXJLqX0i0FgBuLn+mpVHVeLRQ6upH338LdggA4/thXHT2vVWQX7pdBd1r486usZXgpAF8RpDsGJNtf6ei8e5NHTsg0hzVHR9C+Fj89AWuQ7ue+fzV2; JSESSIONID=ABB2A35B91751CA9B2D293F5A04505BE; _gid=GA1.2.1029531470.1575928527; _gat=1',
        'TE': 'Trailer'


        },

    cookies = {"_ga":"GA1.2.1297456970.1574289342","_gid":"GA1.2.1411779365.1574289342","AWSALB":"5v+tPMgooQC0deJBlEGl2wVeUSmwVGJdydie1D6dAZSRAK5eBsmg+DQCdBj8t25YRytC5NIi0TbU3PmDcNMjiyFPTp1xKHgwNjZcDvMRePZjTxthds5DsvelzE2I","JSESSIONID":"310F346AED94D1A345207A3489DCF83D","locale_":"en"}
)
```

but I get this response

```
<ajax-response><redirect><![CDATA[/en/etf-profile.html?0&groupField=none&sortField=ter&sortOrder=asc&from=search&isin=IE00B3VWN518&tab=chart]]></redirect></ajax-response>
```

Why am I not getting a response to the same XML file that I get on my browser when I hit MAX?

Comment: Are you trying to get this response? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajax-response></ajax-response>` because that is why I get.

Comment: @foba the `OP` trying to get the `XML` response of the webpage .https://i.ibb.co/JzCHfX0/Capture.png

Comment: Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Don't use `cookies`, `headers` and `data` in your request. like this `session.get(url)` and you will get proper html response.

Comment: @foba, as  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη said I'm trying to get the xml response that is obtained by clicking max

Comment: @mkadia I tried just with `session.get(url)` but I get only the 1 year range of data, while I'm truing to retrieve the whole range.
Why shall I exclude `data` and `headers` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay below is my solution to obtaining the data you seek:

```py
url = "https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html"

querystring = {
  # Modify this string to get the timeline you want
  # Currently it is set to "max" as you can see
  "0-1.0-tabs-panel-chart-dates-ptl_max":"",
  "groupField":"none",
  "sortField":"ter",
  "sortOrder":"asc",
  "from":"search",
  "isin":"IE00B3VWN518",
  "tab":"chart",
  "_":"1576627890798"}

# Not all of these headers may be necessary
headers = {
    'authority': "www.justetf.com",
    'accept': "application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01",
    'x-requested-with': "XMLHttpRequest",
    'wicket-ajax-baseurl': "en/etf-profile.html?0&amp;groupField=none&amp;sortField=ter&amp;sortOrder=asc&amp;from=search&amp;isin=IE00B3VWN518&amp;tab=chart",
    'wicket-ajax': "true",
    'wicket-focusedelementid': "id27",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
}

session = requests.Session()

# The first request won't return what we want but it sets the cookies
response = session.get( url, params=querystring)

# Cookies have been set now we can make the 2nd request and get the data we want
response = session.get( url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

As a bonus, I have included a link to a repl.it where I actually parse the data and get each individual data point. You can find this [here](https://repl.it/repls/SaltyCloseInstances).

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Though I am a bit confused by the fact that you have to set the cookies with the first `session.get()` and then get the response with the second one. Shall I do this always for ajax requests? Could you point me to a post or article where this is explained? I didn't find good resources about scraping, do you have any recommendation?